# Not able to fetch Exact user details in jsp

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I'm developing Hospital Management System. Here I Wrote some code like below

```
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="reqid" onclick="editRecord(<%=resultset1.getString(1)%>)" style="width:20px; text-align: left;" /></td>
                                <TD colspan="10" style=" text-align: center" ><%= resultset1.getString(2)%> </TD>
                                <TD colspan="10" style=" text-align: center" ><%= resultset1.getString(3)%></TD>
                                <TD colspan="10" style=" text-align: center" ><%= resultset1.getString(4)%></TD>
                                <TD colspan="10" style=" text-align: center"  ><%= resultset1.getString(5)%></TD>
                                <TD colspan="10" style=" text-align: center"  ><a href="pathome.jsp"><button type="button">View</button></TD>
                            </tr>
```

It Displays Following details

```
   patientid    PatientName     DOB    Gender
    PAT39539    xyz         12/03/1993  male    View
    PAT45131    zyx         12/03/1993  male    View
```

upto this working fine but here actually I got some conflict issues like When I click on **view** button on **PAT39539** It showing exact details which consisting that patient. But When I click on **view** button which is related to **PAT45131** it also showing previous patient details, those records are related to **PAT39539**. I want to fetch **PAT45131** patient details? How I can achieve this ? could any one has any Idea please help me

**EDIT**

my pathome.jsp code

```
<div class="article">
                <%
                        String email=(String)session.getAttribute("email");
                        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select patientid, DOB, gender, phone, address from patient where email='"+email+"'");
                        ResultSet rst = pst.executeQuery();

                        %>
                        <% while(rst.next()){%>
                        <table width="600" align="center">
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <h1>Personal Details</h1>

                            <tr><td>Patient ID</td><td><%=rst.getString(1)%></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>D.O.B</td><td><%=rst.getString(2)%></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Gender</td><td><%=rst.getString(3)%></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Phone</td><td><%=rst.getString(4)%></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Address</td><td><%=rst.getString(5)%></td></tr>
                        <%}%>
                        </table>    

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>

                <div class="article">
                                    <p>Please enter n/a if you dont know the details</p>
                    <form action="measurements.jsp" action="post">
                                        <table>

                                            <tr><td>Weight</td><td><input type="text" name="weight" pattern="[0-9]*" maxLength="7"/></td>
                                            <td>Height</td><td><input type="text" name="height"pattern="[0-9]*" maxLength="5"/></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Blood Pressure</td><td><input type="text" name="bp"pattern="[0-9]*" maxLength="3"/></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Sugar Level Before Fasting</td><td><input type="text" name="sugarb4" pattern="[0-9]*" maxLength="5"/></td>
                                            <td>Sugar Level After Fasting</td><td><input type="text" name="sugaraftr" pattern="[0-9]*" maxLength="7"/></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Eye Power Low Vision</td><td><input type="text" name="eyelow" pattern="[0-9]*" maxLength="7"/></td>
                                            <td>Eye Power High Vision</td><td><input type="text" name="eyehigh"pattern="[0-9]*" maxLength="7"/></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Cholesterol</td><td><input type="text" name="chol" pattern="[0-9]*" maxLength="7"/></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td></td><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </form>

                </div>
            </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you share your more code to find out what exact are you doing?

Comment: Each patient has unique details. I'm try to retrieving those patient details in Doctor login account . For that I wrote above code.

Comment: Pass patiend is with pathome.jsp and base on that id display detail of record.

Comment: @SanjayPatel   i Don't know how to pass patientid automatically in pathhome.jsp. Could you please let me know how to do this

Comment: &lt;TD colspan=&quot;10&quot; style=&quot; text-align: center&quot; &gt;&lt;a href=&quot;pathome.jsp?patentid=&lt;%=resulset1.getString(1)%&gt;&quot;&gt;&lt;button type=&quot;button&quot;&gt;View&lt;/button&gt;&lt;/TD&gt; 
Try this

Comment: Ex .<a href="pathome.jsp?patiendid=PAT45131"> and get that id in pathhome jsp.

Comment: @SanjayPatel I doesn't working

Comment: Which email id stored in session? it remain same during entire session incase you change.

Comment: See I edit the question which is consisting my pathome.jsp code

Comment: instead of this  String email=(String)session.getAttribute("email"); get patientid from request.getParameter("patiendid") and fire query on patiendid not on email

Comment: Before you continue writing healthcare-related applications, you urgently need to learn how to correctly use prepared statements.  This code appears to have potentially serious vilnerabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TD colspan="10" style=" text-align: center" ><a href="pathome.jsp?patientId=<%=resultset1.getString(2)%>"><button type="button">View</button></TD>
```

Here is **patientId** is a parameters which will be access on **pathome.jsp**
By using **request.get parameter("patientId");**

```
<%
String patientId=request.getParameter("patientId"):
  PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select patientid, DOB, gender, phone, address from patient where patientId='"+patientId+"'"); ResultSet rst = pst.executeQuery(); %>
```

I hope it will work

Comment: no it is not working, it is not showing as exact patient details

Comment: Did you get parameter value by **request.getParameter()** method

Comment: See my edit in question section which is related to my pathome.jsp code

Comment: Dude are you using form method here

Comment: Ram I have resolved your issue and edited in my answer check it

Comment: Yes I have seen it. I wrote some code in answer check it

Comment: `code`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"`code`

Comment: Ohk this is database server issue 
You should close connection each time whenever open it 
It has been reached at maximum connection limit like 15 instance at a moment

Comment: I did , thanks for your help thanks alot. Its work exactly